# Does Passing Ternary Operator as method argument hamper the performance

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Below is just some sample code, I am sure there are many ways to refactor it but question is:
**Does ternary operator as method argument hamper code performance if code is in such way explained below in loop.**

Tried to search online but haven't received any info about performance.

```
Class employee {

    private int id;  
    private string firstName;  
    private string middleName;  
    private string lastName;  
    private string cellPhone;  
    private string workPhone;  
    private string stNumber;  
    private string stName; 
    private string city;  
    private string state;  
    private string zip;  

    // follow all the getter setter.
}

Class verifyEmployee {

// below loop will throw nullpointer if we don't check null conditions. Provided couple of soultions.New Code 1 and New Code 2.

    ForEach(ListOfOldEmployee oldEmp:ListofOnlyEmployee){
        forEach(ListOfNewEmployee newEmp: ListOfNewEmployee){

            if(firstname based on some condition call verify){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getfirstName(),newEmp.getfirstName())
            } else if(middleName based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getmiddleName(),newEmp.getmiddleName())
            } else if(lastName based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getlastName(),newEmp.getlastName())
            } else if(cellPhone based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getcellPhone(),newEmp.getcellPhone())
            } else if(workPhone based on some condition call verify){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getworkPhone(),newEmp.getworkPhone())
            } else if(stNumber based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getstNumber(),newEmp.getstNumber())
            } else if(stName based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getstName(),newEmp.getstName())
            } else if(city based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getcity(),newEmp.getcity())
            } else if(state based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getstate(),newEmp.getstate())
            } else if(zip based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp.getzip(),newEmp.getzip())
            }
            ///  --- etc follows
        }
    }

    verify(someobject,string,string){   ---- method I don't send the whole object.
        // process something here here.

    }
}
```

New Code : 1 Check the not null conditions before calling forloop

```
Class verifyEmployee {        

    --------- without ternary oprator use code looks so weird and lengthy.

    string firstNameOldEmp = null;  
    string middleNameOldEmp = null;  
    string lastNameOldEmp = null;  
    string cellPhoneOldEmp = null;  
    string workPhoneOldEmp = null;  
    string stNumberOldEmp = null;  
    string stNameOldEmp = null;  
    string cityOldEmp = null;  
    string stateOldEmp = null;  
    string zipOldEmp = null;  

    string firstNameNewEmp = null;  
    string middleNameNewEmp = null;  
    string lastNameNewEmp = null;  
    string cellPhoneNewEmp = null;  
    string workPhoneNewEmp = null;  
    string stNumberNewEmp = null;  
    string stNameNewEmp = null;  
    string cityNewEmp = null;  
    string stateNewEmp = null;  
    string zipNewEmp = null;  

    if(OldEmp!=null){
        string firstNameOldEmp = oldEmp.getfirstName();
        string middleNameOldEmp = oldEmp.getmiddleName();
        string lastNameOldEmp = oldEmp.getlastName();
        string cellPhoneOldEmp = oldEmp.getcellPhone();
        string workPhoneOldEmp = oldEmp.getworkPhone();
        string stNumberOldEmp = oldEmp.getstNumber();
        string stNameOldEmp = oldEmp.getName();
        string cityOldEmp = oldEmp.getcity();
        string stateOldEmp = oldEmp.getstate();
        string zipOldEmp = oldEmp.getzip();
    }

    if(newEmp!=null){
        string firstNameNewEmp = newEmp.getfirstName();
        string middleNameNewEmp = newEmp.getmiddleName();
        string lastNameNewEmp = newEmp.getlastName();
        string cellPhoneNewEmp = newEmp.getcellPhone();
        string workPhoneNewEmp = newEmp.getworkPhone();
        string stNumberNewEmp = newEmp.getstNumber();
        string stNameNewEmp = newEmp.getName();
        string cityNewEmp = newEmp.getcity();
        string stateNewEmp = newEmp.getstate();
        string zipNewEmp = newEmp.getzip();
    }

    ForEach(ListOfOldEmployee oldEmp:ListofOnlyEmployee){
        forEach(ListOfNewEmployee newEmp: ListOfNewEmployee){

            if(firstname based on some condition call verify){
                verify(someobject, firstNameOldEmp,firstNameNewEmp)
            } else if(middleName based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, middleNameOldEmp,middleNameNewEmp)
            } else if(lastName based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, lastNameOldEmp,lastNameNewEmp)
            } else if(cellPhone based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, cellPhoneOldEmp,cellPhoneNewEmp)
            } else if(workPhone based on some condition call verify){
                verify(someobject, workPhoneOldEmp,workPhoneNewEmp)
            } else if(stNumber based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, stNumberOldEmp,stNumberNewEmp)
            } else if(stName based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, stNameOldEmp,stNameNewEmp)
            } else if(city based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, cityOldEmp,cityNewEmp)
            } else if(state based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, stateOldEmp),stateNewEmp)
            } else if(zip based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, zipOldEmp,zipNewEmp)
            }
            ///  --- etc follows
        }
    }
```

> New Code : 2  -- use ternary operator instead

```
Class verifyEmployee {

--- remove all initlization and use the ternary operator instead. Questions is does this hampper the performance if it's used as method argument
--- and we will be checking not null conditions everytime in the loop of list

    ForEach(ListOfOldEmployee oldEmp:ListofOnlyEmployee){
        forEach(ListOfNewEmployee newEmp: ListOfNewEmployee){

            if(firstname based on some condition call verify){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getfirstName():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getfirstName():null)
            } else if(middleName based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getmiddleName():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getmiddleName():null)
            } else if(lastName based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getlastName():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getlastName():null)
            } else if(cellPhone based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getcellPhone():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getcellPhone():null)
            } else if(workPhone based on some condition call verify){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getworkPhone():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getworkPhone():null)
            } else if(stNumber based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getstNumber():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getstNumber():null)
            } else if(stName based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getstName():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getstName():null)
            } else if(city based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getcity():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getcity():null)
            } else if(state based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getstate():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getstate():null)
            } else if(zip based on some condition){
                verify(someobject, oldEmp!=null?oldEmp.getzip():null,newEmp!=null?newEmp.getzip():null)
            }
            ///  --- etc follows
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Modern JVM does optimizations and whatever the difference is between the two, that is ridiculous (some nanoseconds).

Comment: You should rather focus on the readability and the maintainability of your code. And on these points for the shown code, you have really space for improvements.

Comment: This code is somewhat impenetrable. Write code for humans to read. Have you proved that this code is a performance bottleneck? How? I would strongly consider rewriting this using a [chain-of-responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). Also see [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: Also, your code isn't Java - for example it's `class` not `Class`. Methods and variables in Java are **always** in `camelCase`, `PascalCase` is reserved for class names. It's `String` rather than `string`.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question about performance, I doubt there is any substantial difference. You could check performance using System.nanoTime() before and after your code and look at how long each approach takes. However, beware of JIT optimization; you should run the code in a loop and look at a sample of times. I've found the first pass is slow and the others fairly steady.

As comments have noted, the second solution is very hard to read. For that reason, I suggest using the first.

Comment: This answer is not backed by anything "_I doubt_" - so do I, but have you any proof? Anything beyond a feeling, a guess? Furthermore, the only way to microbench Java is with a microbench framework - any other suggestion is just wrong. Finally, and this is just my opinion, the first solution is almost as awful - couldn't recommend using either option.

Comment: I explained how to get "proof". No, you don't need a "microbench framework" to get a good idea of how a method performs.

Comment: You really do, just using `nanoTime` will give you a very messy picture - not taking into account GC, JIT, tiered compilation, class loading, class unloading and so many more things. Naive benchmarks give you naive results, to improve results you add warmup, iterations, statistical techniques to determine useful values. At that point, you _are_ building a microbench framework. There is no excuse not to use a proven framework from the outset.

Comment: As per readability purpose 1st solution is good. Only issue is code become lengthier.Anyway I don't see much code where anyone sending ternary operator as method argument so bit hesitant in first.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Your comments are mildly offensive and not constructive. Also, here is a good quote from Admiral Gorshkov. "'Better' is the enemy of 'Good Enough'" Overkill benchmarking on such a trivial question is poor practice.